# How to automatically reconnect/reboot remote computer when internet disconnects

Tags: internet, connection, remote

Normally I work connected to my computer in the office (Windows 7) via Team Viewer. Sometimes the internet connection fails and the connection is lost, so I have to hit the streets and go to my office to restart the connection (which is not too bad, but not so nice when I am in another city).

I have used the Task Scheduler to reboot every day my computer, as it is more or less guaranteed that the connection would work again no matter what. This is obviously a simple resource but I need something that really solves the problem.

I am not so good at Linux or languages (so please be simple and clear ;))  but I would try anything that is recommended.

Can Task scheduler start a command if the internet connection is lost?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a script like this, and schedule it to run on machine startup. This script test the connection for IP 8.8.8.8 (could be changed) if the ping is ok just test it after 5 minutes, if ping fails force a restart.

```
#!/bin/bash
{
sleep 180 # wait 3 minutes on machine startup
while true;
do
  #if [ping] -->  0 means host reachable
  if ping -c 5 8.8.8.8; then
    sleep 300 ; #line stable , test after 5min
  else
     shutdown -r now
done
} &> /dev/null
```

Comment: This would work if it was a linux machine, but from the question it seems it is a windows machine that needs rebooting although it is not quite clear.

Comment: `I am not so good at Linux or languages` :) it's a little bit confusing